# Old school C# utility that sends millions of 80k files over socket connection hangs the UI

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have an existing utility that sends xml files over a socket connection and does so by creating threads using the old school:

```
FolderThread ft = new FolderThread(this, new DirectoryInfo(sourceFolder));
Thread t = new Thread(ft.Start);
t.Start();
```

The problem is that the code ignores nice things like letting the UI show any information or respond to events. Its very old school.

I'd like to refactor it to use something available in Visual Studio 2013.

I read about Task-based Asynchronous (TAP) but it sounds like it is designed for short background tasks. When I send a file over the socket connection, it might take anywhere from 1000ms to 4000ms to finish and I'd like to have a configurable amount of threads.

**Is TAP still the man for the job or something like BackgroundWorker an easier and better solution?**

If you can, provide a link to example material.

Comment: You can use tasks for this, you can also write custom logic that only sends off x number of tasks at a time then waits for them all to complete before sending the next batch.

Comment: I found this series of articles helpful: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html

Comment: " it sounds like it is designed for short background tasks" why do you think that?

Comment: Tasks aren't going to solve your problem.  For this workload they're irrelevant.  It'll be easier just to add UI.BeginInvoke type code into the thread to send UI updates.  A static volatile Boolean field somewhere should handle cancellation signals.

Comment: If your goal is to have more threads doing this stuff then you need to have multiple connections; one thread should have no problem saturating an entire socket, even on a bad day.

Comment: Threading (whichever way you do it) is the way to go. Your problem, IMHO, is in how you are refreshing the UI. Is it a desktop [fat] client?

Comment: TAP and async/await are very well suited to even the heftiest of IO jobs and don't require the explicit creation of threads to operate. Dealing with IO with TAP **is** a short background task (or a bunch of them). In an async wait for IO, the thread is yielded back to the ThreadPool until something interesting happens, whereupon the continuation is run, possibly in another thread... it doesn't really matter where. You don't need to think about this in terms of "a thread per conversation"... in fact, doing so will lead to a sub-optimal solution.

Comment: If this thread is sending 80k files over a single connection, I don't think there's anything wrong with explicitly creating a thread. You can add events to the `FolderThread` class and attach a handler where you're creating `ft`, as long as you follow hoodaticus' advice to `BeginInvoke` anything UI related.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Going to study these comments in the morning.

Comment: @spender I'm concerned that I don't have my head in the right mode because with what you've stated - I can't at the moment go and write code to match. I myself am old school and think in "Threads". Do you happen to know of a tutorial on TAP to help old school developers like myself?

Comment: @adv12  ah!  Thanks. Studying https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html right now.

Comment: @Juan yes it is a command line utility.

Comment: I see. Well, one of my core beliefs is "if it ain't broken, don't fix it", so being it's a console application, it should just be a matter of writing status to the console from the thread. You don't have to create a new line every time. You can display a counter single line and update it as the files are sent. Since you are just displaying the number on screen, you can just use a static variable without worrying about concurrency. It's not the cleanest but it's the easiest and less time consuming. You can also get fancy and add events and what not.

Comment: You also may create a simple pipeline in `TPL Dataflow`, which can be managed with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` and use the `async` operations in blocks. Also it's very easy to use `TPL Dataflow` with `Rx.Net` to notify user about the progress being done.